# How to draw line and erase the line I draw on ImageView Android Xamarin

Tags: java, android, canvas, xamarin, imageview

I want to let the user to draw lines on the image and user can erase tline they draw. So far I can draw lines on the custom ImageView created as below. However, I tried a lot of method and all of them draw black line when I selected erase mode. I want the part after earse still is the Image I set and implement the erase just like drawing lines. How can I do this?

```
public class PaintView : ImageView
{
    private Paint _Paint = new Paint();
    private Paint ErasePaint= new Paint();
    public Bitmap _Bmp;
    private Canvas _Canvas = null;

    private PointF _StartPt = new PointF();
    private PointF _EndPt = new PointF();

    public int status=1;  //1 draw, 0 erase

    public PaintView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {

    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _Paint = new Paint ();
        _Paint.Color = new Color (255, 255, 255);
        _Paint.StrokeWidth = 5;
        _Paint.StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round;

        int alpha = 3;

        _Bmp = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(_Bmp,_Bmp.Width*alpha, _Bmp.Height*alpha, false);
        _Canvas = new Canvas(_Bmp);

        this.SetImageBitmap(_Bmp);
    }



    override public bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    { 
        if (status == 1) {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
            case MotionEventActions.Down: 
                _StartPt.Set(e.GetX() - 1, e.GetY() - 1);// for just a tapping
                DrawLine(e);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move: 
                DrawLine(e);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up: 
                DrawLine(e);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (status == 0) {

            switch (e.Action)
            {
            case MotionEventActions.Down: 
                _StartPt.Set(e.GetX() - 1, e.GetY() - 1);// for just a tapping
                eraseCanvas(e);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move: 
                eraseCanvas(e);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up: 
                eraseCanvas(e);
                break;
            }

        }

        return true;

    }

    private void DrawLine(MotionEvent e)
    {
        _EndPt.Set(e.GetX(), e.GetY());

        _Canvas.DrawLine(_StartPt.X, _StartPt.Y, _EndPt.X, _EndPt.Y, _Paint);

        _StartPt.Set(_EndPt);
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void eraseCanvas(MotionEvent e)
    {
        _EndPt.Set(e.GetX(), e.GetY());

        ErasePaint.Color = Color.Transparent;
        ErasePaint.StrokeWidth = 5;
        ErasePaint.SetXfermode (new PorterDuffXfermode (PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));
        _Canvas.DrawLine(_StartPt.X, _StartPt.Y, _EndPt.X, _EndPt.Y, ErasePaint);

        _StartPt.Set(_EndPt);
        Invalidate();
    }

}
```

Comment: After user lifts his finger - does the black line disappear showing the picture or does it stay black?

Answer (score 0):

Well then, the way I do it in my app is to set the bitmap I draw on as a background to the canvas View on initialization - this should make the line go transparent after the drawing operation is done. I am not really familiar with Xamarin but in Android Java I just go something like:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
canvas.setBitmapDrawable(bd);  //or this.setBitmapDrawable(bd);
```

after instantiating the `Canvas`. It's because the xfer mode clear scrapes off everything showing `View` beneath the `Canvas`, so the line stays black. I believe you should adapt it to your code fairly easy.

If it works as I described (the line is black during drawing, and then poof - goes transparent), then to make it transparent right away, the way to go for me was to turn off hardware acceleration when drawing with `Mode.Clear`, again, Android Java:

```
boolean bool = "rubber".equals(tool);
if (bool) {
    this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, canvasPaint);    //or canvas.setLayer...
}
//drawing stuff
if (bool) {
    this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, canvasPaint);
}
```

Good luck, let me know how did it go or if you need some clarification or something. :)

Comment: Thanks for rely! Already fixed this by using the framelayout to overlay two this PaintViews and enable drawing on the top one. So I can both draw and erase (which is drawing black line). This solve my problem. I will try your method later. Thanks!